# How to profile browser page load using Javascript (Library)?

Tags: browser, javascript, page-load-time

I've been doing a lot of research on this, but I figure I could crowd-source with what I have and see if anyone can offer additions to what I have.  So I want to be able to determine page load time using JS.  Not just page load as a single number, but as a breakdown.

First what I found was a new W3C Specification (Draft):
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html

This would be perfect, however its limited to Chrome, and IE, and it's still inconsistent between the browsers.

But now I have found Real User Monitoring (RUM) by New Relic that is based off of a Javascript Library by Steve Souders.  From what I can tell they can determine the same data that I saw from the new w3c Draft.

It seems that they are using HTTP Archive: http://code.google.com/p/httparchive/

However, I cannot seem to find any information on page performance or load, so I wasn't sure if I was looking at the correct library.

Now of course, if there is anything else out there, that could provide more information on page profiling, I am welcomed to the information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Boomerang.js (https://github.com/yahoo/boomerang) by Yahoo.

Should allow you to roll your own RUM and does graceful degradation so you should still get some information from browsers without navigation.timing.

Also if you've got access to Windows have a play with dynatrace's tools - gives quite a good insight into what it going on during page load (in IE and FF)

Comment: Boomerang seems unfortunately a bit outdated based on their website